# How to truncate a list to provide specialization

Tags: java, list, encapsulation, truncate

Let us imagine the `Phone` and `Person` interfaces:

```
public interface Phone {
    String getNumber();
    // ...
}

public interface Person {
    String getName();
    List<Phone> getPhones();
    // ...
}
```

I do not want to change these classes, they stores only data, but I want to show them together, to avoid iteration over millions of register twice, once on the controller and another on view via datatable, and to avoid doing logic on the view (not to manipulate data), I managed to elaborate this solution:

```
abstract class PhonedPerson implements Person {
    private String phoneNumbers;

    public String getPhoneNumbers() {
        if (phoneNumbers == null) {
            phoneNumbers = StringUtils.join(
                CollectionUtils.collect(getPhones(), new Transformer() {
                    @Override
                    public Object transform(Object input) {
                        return ((Phone) input).getNumber();
                    }
                }),
                ", "
            );
        }
        return phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

How can I convert a `List<Person>` to a `List<PhonedPerson>` without iterate all items?

Comment: Do you have another implementation of Person? Because in your list of Person, you have to put objects of a concrete class. So why don't you just instantiate PhonedPerson from the start?

Comment: @JPMoresmau, indeed, there is the `PersonImpl`, which data is returned from the database, but the repository returns it as `Person`, so I am trying to truncate it to `PhonedPerson`, doing it for one single object it works, but to a list do not.

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work? You can have a function that transforms a Person into a PhonedPerson, so you can just run CollectionUtils.collect on your list of PersonImpl.

Comment: I wonder why just doing `(List<PhonedPerson>)persons` do not work assuming `(PhonedPerson)person` does. If I use `collect` or `foreach` I would be doing the iteration twice, once on controller, another on view, If possible I want to avoid that as well.

Comment: Your cast from a PersonImpl to a PhonedPerson may compile but it won't work at runtime of course. And compared to the time spent retrieving data from the database, looping again on the java objects to mutate them to a new instance will not be long. Also, don't make PhonedPerson implements Person, just have it holding the Person in a field, so you don't need to duplicate the whole object.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand really what bugs you, can you post the higher level code that manipulates the lists instead?

Comment: Well, I am just concerned about performance, because datatable will do iteration too, I wonder how interception works, it may help me.